# PowerShell - Having trouble setting Specific Recycle Time in IIS App Pool

Tags: powershell, iis

When it comes to IIS App Pool Recycling, under the `Recycling` settings, you can set a `Specific Time` to Recycle. You can also set multiple times by doing `00:15, 04:30`. See following screenshot.

[image]

I am attempting to set multiple Recycle Times using PowerShell. The odd thing is, when I run my code - it only shows `00:15` in the GUI - not `00:15` and `04:30`.

[image]

But - if I run this check, it shows both times set.

```
Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

[image]

Now, if I go into the GUI and add a time that way - it shows, but it wipes out `04:30`.

[image]

[image]

I am wanting to know why when I set multiple times in PS - they do not all show in the GUI. Other people can run my code and see both times in the GUI. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$RecycleTime1 = '00:15'
$RecycleTime2 = '04:30'
$PrivateMemory = 1468006     
$sites = Get-ChildItem 'IIS:\AppPools\' <# | Where-Object { $_.recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.TotalMilliseconds -gt 1 } #>

Clear-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value=$RecycleTime1}
New-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value=$RecycleTime2}
Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like value may need an index. Trying to figure out if so.

```
AppCmd set config
 -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools
 "/+applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[@0,value='04:00:00']"
 /commit:apphost
```

Comment: I have no explanation, but I wonder if you can set _all_ values _at once_, say with `@{value=$RecycleTime1, $RecycleTime2}`, which _may_ bypass your problem. Also, the fact that you're using `New-ItemProperty` after `Set-ItemProperty` may be problematic - though I would then expect the _last_ value passed to "win".

Comment: `Set` sets the default and `New` adds more. Per the docs that is proper. `00:15` always shows in the GUI. I tried the `@{}` initially but no such luck. Thanks for the reply!!

Comment: No go. Thanks though! It's weird because it works for others. It works for me technically but doesn't show in GUI.

Comment: It's definitely recycling at 04:30 though. `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'w3wp.exe'" | Select-Object Name, @{"name"="ApplicationPool";expression={(($_).CommandLine).split('"')[1] }},@{"name"="Starttime";expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate)}}` so that's a win.

Comment: I tested your codes on my PC and it works for IIS. Unfortunately can't reproduce your problem. So the multiple recycle times you added via PS are all working fine for you, but only one is showing up in IIS. In general, working fine is lucky. Did you check the applicationhost.config when changing recycle time via PS? Or restart the application pool.